# Why is Kinect working but freenect.launch and openni.launch fail?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have used Kinect with my own systems for years.  My installation works:
Right now using Lubuntu Xenial 16.04.1 64 bit.The Kinect system is:

- OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x64-v1.5.7.10    (built from source and patched to fix
  a USB problem so the Kinect motor control works)
- Sensor-Bin-Linux-x64-v5.1.2.1

I would like to use ROS.  I installed packages from Synaptic:

- ros-kinetic-freenect-stack
- ros-kinetic-lib-freenect

I can launch the system, but Kinect device does not connect and no data is sent to rviz.

```
roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch
```

I also tried installing from Synaptic:

- ros-kinetic-openni-camera
- ros-kinetic-openni-launch

Launching with `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch` gives the following suspicious warnings:

```
Warning: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might cause loss of data..

[ INFO] [1474760990.182270093]: Number devices connected: 2

[ INFO] [1474760990.283229629]: 1. device on bus 002:06 is a SensorKinect (2ae) from PrimeSense (45e) with serial id '0'

[ INFO] [1474760990.283294658]: 2. device on bus 002:06 is a SensorV2 (2ae) from PrimeSense (45e) with serial id 'A00361A13780044A'
```

Launching with `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch device_id:=A00361A13780044A` selects the right device, but the Kinect does not connect and no data is sent to rviz.

I have uninstalled and re-installed the packages various times to no avail.  Surprisingly the ROS packages do not break my own installation, as they used to in the past.

I am at a complete loss as to how to debug this.  The more I read the documentation the more confused I get about the bewildering number of versions and alternative components that exist (often with very similar names).  Given that I have a working Kinect interface based on openni and avin driver, what can be going wrong ?  Is there a sure way to get this going from the repositories ?  Could my installation be breaking the ROS installation ?  Infuriatingly I believe that at the start both ROS and my installation were working simultaneously, but the something broke ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244403/why-is-kinect-working-but-freenect.launch-and-openni.launch-fail-?/) by [elpidiovaldez](https://answers.ros.org/users/28066/elpidiovaldez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2016-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't want to waste anyone's time on this.  I finally fixed the problem by fully removing and re-installing libfreenect-dev and libfreenect0.5 from the ubuntu repositories.

---

Originally posted by [elpidiovaldez](https://answers.ros.org/users/28066/elpidiovaldez/) with karma: 142 on 2016-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [faisal](https://answers.ros.org/users/6951/faisal/) on 2017-03-27**:
I have the same problem to read depth image from Kinect with ROS Kinetic. Could you please share steps to remove and install those libraries? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I spent several hours trying to solve that issue and finally I have found the solution (I know the topic is a little outdated, but it might be helpful for others). Which is pathetically easy :)

I am using  [ph4m](https://github.com/ph4m/SensorKinect.git) version of SensorKinect, cause [avin2](https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect) failed during building and ROS-Kinetic.

Shorter version of error I used to receive by executing `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch`

```
...
[ INFO] [1512932358.038225148]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
[ INFO] [1512932360.867815700]: Number devices connected: 2
[ INFO] [1512932360.968706220]: 1. device on bus 001:08 is a SensorKinect (2ae) from PrimeSense (45e) with serial id '0'
[ INFO] [1512932360.968758126]: 2. device on bus 001:08 is a SensorV2 (2ae) from PrimeSense (45e) with serial id 'B00367611818052B'
[ INFO] [1512932360.969746663]: Searching for device with index = 1
nodelet: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:641: typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator*() const [with T = xn::NodeInfo; typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type = xn::NodeInfo&]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-1] process has died [pid 6501, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=camera_nodelet_manager __log:=/root/.ros/log/b5542c0e-dddb-11e7-b428-448a5b4484c7/camera-camera_nodelet_manager-1.log].
log file: /root/.ros/log/b5542c0e-dddb-11e7-b428-448a5b4484c7/camera-camera_nodelet_manager-1*.log
[FATAL] [1512932372.450632995]: Failed to load nodelet '/camera/disparity_registered_hw` of type `depth_image_proc/disparity` to manager `camera_nodelet_manager'
....
```

To fix that I went to openni.launch file and changed
this:  `<arg name="device_id" default="#1" />`
into that:  `<arg name="device_id" default="B00367611818052B" />`, which is ID read from error message.

---

Originally posted by [Totalq](https://answers.ros.org/users/32935/totalq/) with karma: 11 on 2017-12-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1